# Whats an appropriate map projection for georeferencing aerial photos?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I have some aerial photos that were shot from directly overhead a 5x5 mile property. They were then mosaiced to create a continuous overhead tiff of the entire property.

I am now going to georeference in ArcMap using satellite imagery as my base reference. Is there one map projection that would be more appropriate than others for using as reference?

Edit: By appropriate I mean - which projection will results in the most visually similar look to an overhead, aerial photo? Using WGS84 is too wide and stretched.

Comment: Choosing the "right" projection depends on the area/location, extent you want to map and your preference regarding the distortions. And it's not related to the type of the data (vector or raster). If you are using imagery from AGOL, then your projection would be Web Mercator - you have to choose the same projection as the source's

Comment: Please edit your area of interest into your question.

Comment: Matej: you don't need to use the source's projection to georeference with it, you can transform between coordinates. It really shouldn't matter on such a local scale, a local Orthographic would be fine - I'd say it depends more on what you want to use it for and the features/limitations imposed by that.

Comment: I guess what I am getting at is what projection results in the most visually similar look to an aerial photograph. WGS 84 looks wide and warped here in Montana. Using the NAD83 looks better but does not quite look like the aerial.

Comment: Personal opinion, I'd go with the appropriate State Plane CRS for your area for minimal distortion. However I think you may be confusing a couple of terms - georeferencing and orthorectification. Georeferencing will get you close, but it's not as precise as orthorectification. And if there are mountainous areas (ie western MT as opposed to eastern) you can expect some severe distortions in the imagery no matter what you do - which should be clear from the sat imagery. Map projections are flat and have no perspective - imagery does.